# User Defined tabel types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I am writing a stored procedure that needs to use a user defined table type in order to delete multiple rows without having to run the stored procedure multiple times. My question is that is it possible to write one user defined table type (instead of 17; one for each table) and add a column that specifies the table it is related to. For example here is my delete statement:

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE A_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM UserDefinedTableType WHERE TblClm = 'Table1'
```

Can I use the same user defined table type for the above statement and the following statement

```
DELETE FROM Table2
WHERE A_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM UserDefinedTableType WHERE TblClm = 'Table2'
```

I am wondering if this will work or not. I am new to this concept and I haven't been able to find any good documentation on using User Defined Table Types this way.

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this approach but it is not something I have seen before. I would use a join in your delete statement instead of IN but honestly it will end up being the same thing.

Comment: Okay thanks. I could use a join but I just prefer IN so I can explicitly define which IDs are being deleted. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You would join on ID. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little long for a comment and the formatting would get murdered. Here is what I meant by using a join instead of in.

```
DELETE t1
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN UserDefinedTableType udt ON t1.A_ID = udt.ID 
WHERE udt.TblClm = 'Table1'
```

Comment: I know what you meant by using a join I use them all the time I just prefer IN because it is a little cleaner to me.